# Firebase: Find the parent uid using a users username

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

How would I find the UID of the user by only having the username.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do that by running a query:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://yours.firebaseio.com/users");
var query = ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo('tom');
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(tomSnapshot) {
    console.log('We found a tom with uid: '+tomSnapshot.key());
  });
});
```

This is covered in the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries), which is well worth a read.